# c# proxy authentication using wininet

Tags: c#, authentication, proxy, credentials, wininet

c# proxy authentication using wininet;
I should ensure that the proxy works only within the winforms appplication( webbrowser control), not systemwide.

This is the proxy class I use;

```
public static class WinInetInterop
    {
        public static string applicationName;

        [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern IntPtr InternetOpen(
            string lpszAgent, int dwAccessType, string lpszProxyName,
            string lpszProxyBypass, int dwFlags);

        [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool InternetCloseHandle(IntPtr hInternet);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        private struct INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST
        {
            public int Size;

            // The connection to be set. NULL means LAN.
            public System.IntPtr Connection;

            public int OptionCount;
            public int OptionError;

            // List of INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTIONs.
            public System.IntPtr pOptions;
        }
        private enum INTERNET_OPTION
        {
            // Sets or retrieves an INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST structure that specifies
            // a list of options for a particular connection.
            INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION = 75,

            // Notify the system that the registry settings have been changed so that
            // it verifies the settings on the next call to InternetConnect.
            INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED = 39,

            // Causes the proxy data to be reread from the registry for a handle.
            INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH = 37

        }

        private enum INTERNET_PER_CONN_OptionEnum
        {
            INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS = 1,
            INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER = 2,
            INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_BYPASS = 3,
            INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTOCONFIG_URL = 4,
            INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTODISCOVERY_FLAGS = 5,
            INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTOCONFIG_SECONDARY_URL = 6,
            INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTOCONFIG_RELOAD_DELAY_MINS = 7,
            INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTOCONFIG_LAST_DETECT_TIME = 8,
            INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTOCONFIG_LAST_DETECT_URL = 9,
            INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS_UI = 10
        }
        private const int INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT = 1;  // direct to net
        private const int INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG = 0; // read registry
                                                            /// <summary>
                                                            /// Constants used in INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTON struct.
                                                            /// </summary>
        private enum INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONN_FLAGS
        {
            PROXY_TYPE_DIRECT = 0x00000001,   // direct to net
            PROXY_TYPE_PROXY = 0x00000002,   // via named proxy
            PROXY_TYPE_AUTO_PROXY_URL = 0x00000004,   // autoproxy URL
            PROXY_TYPE_AUTO_DETECT = 0x00000008   // use autoproxy detection
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Used in INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION.
        /// When create a instance of OptionUnion, only one filed will be used.
        /// The StructLayout and FieldOffset attributes could help to decrease the struct size.
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        private struct INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_OptionUnion
        {
            // A value in INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONN_FLAGS.
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public int dwValue;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public System.IntPtr pszValue;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftValue;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION
        {
            // A value in INTERNET_PER_CONN_OptionEnum.
            public int dwOption;
            public INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_OptionUnion Value;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Sets an Internet option.
        /// </summary>
        [DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool InternetSetOption(
            IntPtr hInternet,
            INTERNET_OPTION dwOption,
            IntPtr lpBuffer,
            int lpdwBufferLength);

        /// <summary>
        /// Queries an Internet option on the specified handle. The Handle will be always 0.
        /// </summary>
        [DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true,
            EntryPoint = "InternetQueryOption")]
        private extern static bool InternetQueryOptionList(
            IntPtr Handle,
            INTERNET_OPTION OptionFlag,
            ref INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST OptionList,
            ref int size);

        /// <summary>
        /// Set the proxy server for LAN connection.
        /// </summary>
        public static bool SetConnectionProxy(string proxyServer)
        {

            IntPtr hInternet = InternetOpen(applicationName, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, null, null, 0);

            //// Create 3 options.
            //INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION[] Options = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION[3];

            // Create 2 options.
            INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION[] Options = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION[2];

            // Set PROXY flags.
            Options[0] = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION();
            Options[0].dwOption = (int)INTERNET_PER_CONN_OptionEnum.INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS;
            Options[0].Value.dwValue = (int)INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONN_FLAGS.PROXY_TYPE_PROXY;

            // Set proxy name.
            Options[1] = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION();
            Options[1].dwOption =
                (int)INTERNET_PER_CONN_OptionEnum.INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER;
            Options[1].Value.pszValue = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(proxyServer);

            //// Set proxy bypass.
            //Options[2] = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION();
            //Options[2].dwOption =
            //    (int)INTERNET_PER_CONN_OptionEnum.INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_BYPASS;
            //Options[2].Value.pszValue = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(“local”);

            //// Allocate a block of memory of the options.
            //System.IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(Options[0])
            //    + Marshal.SizeOf(Options[1]) + Marshal.SizeOf(Options[2]));

            // Allocate a block of memory of the options.
            System.IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(Options[0])
                + Marshal.SizeOf(Options[1]));

            System.IntPtr current = buffer;

            // Marshal data from a managed object to an unmanaged block of memory.
            for (int i = 0; i < Options.Length; i++)
            {
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(Options[i], current, false);
                // current = (System.IntPtr)((int)current + Marshal.SizeOf(Options[i])); 
                current = (System.IntPtr)((Environment.Is64BitProcess ? current.ToInt64() : current.ToInt32()) + Marshal.SizeOf(Options[i]));
            }

            // Initialize a INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST instance.
            INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST option_list = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST();

            // Point to the allocated memory.
            option_list.pOptions = buffer;

            // Return the unmanaged size of an object in bytes.
            option_list.Size = Marshal.SizeOf(option_list);

            // IntPtr.Zero means LAN connection.
            option_list.Connection = IntPtr.Zero;

            option_list.OptionCount = Options.Length;
            option_list.OptionError = 0;
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(option_list);

            // Allocate memory for the INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST instance.
            IntPtr intptrStruct = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(size);

            // Marshal data from a managed object to an unmanaged block of memory.
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(option_list, intptrStruct, true);

            // Set internet settings.
            bool bReturn = InternetSetOption(hInternet,
                INTERNET_OPTION.INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION, intptrStruct, size);

            // Free the allocated memory.
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(buffer);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(intptrStruct);
            InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);

            // Throw an exception if this operation failed.
            if (!bReturn)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Set Internet Option Failed!");
            }

            return bReturn;
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Backup the current options for LAN connection.
        /// Make sure free the memory after restoration. 
        /// </summary>
        private static INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST GetSystemProxy()
        {

            // Query following options. 
            INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION[] Options = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION[3];

            Options[0] = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION();
            Options[0].dwOption = (int)INTERNET_PER_CONN_OptionEnum.INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS;
            Options[1] = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION();
            Options[1].dwOption = (int)INTERNET_PER_CONN_OptionEnum.INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER;
            Options[2] = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION();
            Options[2].dwOption = (int)INTERNET_PER_CONN_OptionEnum.INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_BYPASS;

            // Allocate a block of memory of the options.
            System.IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(Options[0])
                + Marshal.SizeOf(Options[1]) + Marshal.SizeOf(Options[2]));

            System.IntPtr current = (System.IntPtr)buffer;

            // Marshal data from a managed object to an unmanaged block of memory.
            for (int i = 0; i < Options.Length; i++)
            {
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(Options[i], current, false);
                current = (System.IntPtr)((int)current + Marshal.SizeOf(Options[i]));
            }

            // Initialize a INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST instance.
            INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST Request = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST();

            // Point to the allocated memory.
            Request.pOptions = buffer;

            Request.Size = Marshal.SizeOf(Request);

            // IntPtr.Zero means LAN connection.
            Request.Connection = IntPtr.Zero;

            Request.OptionCount = Options.Length;
            Request.OptionError = 0;
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(Request);

            // Query internet options. 
            bool result = InternetQueryOptionList(IntPtr.Zero,
                INTERNET_OPTION.INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION,
                ref Request, ref size);
            if (!result)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Set Internet Option Failed!");
            }

            return Request;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Restore the options for LAN connection.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name=”request”></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool RestoreSystemProxy()
        {

            IntPtr hInternet = InternetOpen(applicationName, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, null, null, 0);

            INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST request = GetSystemProxy();
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(request);

            // Allocate memory. 
            IntPtr intptrStruct = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(size);

            // Convert structure to IntPtr 
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(request, intptrStruct, true);

            // Set internet options.
            bool bReturn = InternetSetOption(hInternet,
                INTERNET_OPTION.INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION,
                intptrStruct, size);

            // Free the allocated memory.
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(request.pOptions);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(intptrStruct);

            if (!bReturn)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Set Internet Option Failed!");
            }

            // Notify the system that the registry settings have been changed and cause
            // the proxy data to be reread from the registry for a handle.
            InternetSetOption(hInternet, INTERNET_OPTION.INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED,
                IntPtr.Zero, 0);
            InternetSetOption(hInternet, INTERNET_OPTION.INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH,
                IntPtr.Zero, 0);

            InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);

            return bReturn;
        }

    }
```

And I use the class this way and it works fine;

WinInetInterop.RestoreSystemProxy();
  WinInetInterop.SetConnectionProxy(123.456.789.99:80);

Since good proxy services always require authentication, I had to use proxy authetication like this;
123.456.789.99:80:username:password
and WinInetInterop.SetConnectionProxy(123.456.789.99:80:username:password) doesn't work.

I googled web but couldn't find solution other than this;

"You could always use straight WinINet functions to do proxy auth once you get the 407 response from the proxy.  Here is an article on that (no I do not have a .NET sample but you could write one I am sure): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384220(v=vs.85).aspx"

Since I am a newbie and thus couldn't write codes for this.
I tried for a few days but could not solve it. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

For proxy authentication, the WebBroser ActiveX control calls the host ole client site's IServiceProvider.QueryService method to look up its SID_IAuthenticate service.

For WinForms, the client site is the [WebBrowser.WebBrowserSite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.webbrowsersite(v=vs.110).aspx) class. You can derive from it to add your own IServiceProvider and IAuthenticate implementation then Override the WebBrowser.CreateWebBrowserSiteBase method to use your extended ole client site instead of the default one.

Comment: whaaaaaaaaaaaaat?